In the 1999 movie The Matrix, what is the news reader software that is being used?

The above is a screenshot from the film. The application icons seem reminiscent of the Tkinter Perl applications from the late 2000s, which would suggest a Gtk1 or Gtk2 icon set(?)
What is this newsreader that he is using?

It very well could be some custom mockup for the film.  The "Searching..." looks like the film's own distinctive font in their own distinctive shade of green.  And the UI looks a lot clunkier than any consumer software of the late 90's that I can think of.

I'd agree with @NateEldredge on UI layout grounds. Having the buttons floating over the underlying boxes like that was certainly possible, but not something I remember anyone doing, even in things made in things like Visual Basic or Delphi where you drag-and-drop positioned elements absolutely rather than using layout helpers that prevented overlap like you'd find in GTK+.

When you wrote “news reader” and 1999, I immediately thought of netnews (aka usenet).

This page on the HUDS+GUIS site shows that interface in the section on Thomas Anderson's computer, so it would appear that it is a mockup created by a company called Studio C.

It does indeed like it was custom built for the film. Thanks for finding this! I guess I will see if I can bug the creators for a bit more information on what the buttons on the UI were, or what they were inspired by
